Maximizing a polynomial involving factorials
I'm trying to maximize the polynomial
$$\frac{(n_1+n_2+n_3)!(n_2+n_3+n_4)!(n_3+n_4+n_5)!(n_4+n_5+n_1)!(n_5+n_1+n_2)!}{n_1!n_2!n_3!n_4!n_5!}$$
under the constraint $n_1+n_2+n_3+n_4+n_5=n$, where all of them are non-negative integers.
It seems that the maximum is attained when one of them is $n$ and others are $0$'s. I have tried proving it by making some local adjustments (for example setting $n_1=n_1+1$ and $n_2=n_2-1$ or setting $n_1=n_1+n_2$ and $n_2=0$ when $n_1>n_2$) but it didn't work very well bucause the case when all $n_i$'s are around $\frac{n}{5}$ also gives a relatively large value.
I can prove that if at least one of them is $0$, then the maximum can be attained only when $n_i=n$ for some $i$, but then I got stuck because I can't find a good condition that makes the "interior point" (meaning that when none of the $n_i$'s is $0$) a "local maximum" (meaning that it won't grow larger when applying some simple adjustment on $n_i$'s).

I made an exhaustive simulation ($n_1\le n_2\le n_3\le n_4$) for $n=17$ (https://www.cjoint.com/doc/24_09/NICiltU7QO4_rrr.txt) and it seems effectively that only one number equal to $n$ is the maximum, but reached also if three of them are $0$. I also made one for $n=15$ (not published) to see if perfect divisibility by $5$ changes something, but no, it is similar.

Interestingly, for the 3 variable case $\frac{(n_1+n_2)!(n_2+n_3)!(n_1+n_3)!}{n_1!n_2!n_3!}$ subject to $n_1+n_2+n_3=n$ this does not hold: then the maximum is obtained near equidistribution $n_i \simeq n/3$.
